# How to choose an appropriate smoothing factor for scipy.interpolate.UnivariateSpline

Tags: python, scipy, interpolation, curve-fitting, smoothing

I'm trying to create cubic spline curves using `scipy.interpolate.UnivariateSpline` but I'm having trouble finding an appropriate value for `s`, the smoothing factor.

At `s=0`, each datapoint becomes a knot and the curve goes through every point. On the other hand, a high value for `s` returns a curve with 2 knots.

Ideally, I would like a curve with more than 2 knots for a better fit and I definitely do not want a curve that goes through every point. I believe that a curve with around 5 knots would be a good balance between goodness of fit and smoothness.

Currently, I am making curves with `UnivariateSpline` and adjusting the smoothness until the number of knots was around 5. Obviously, this is not the best process.

Is there a better computational or statistical method for determining the smoothness factor based on a set of data?

Answer (score 2):

Scipy itself uses this heuristic (from the docs):

> Positive smoothing factor used to choose the number of knots. Number of knots will be increased until the smoothing condition is
>   satisfied:
>
> ```
> sum((w[i] * (y[i]-spl(x[i])))**2, axis=0) <= s
> ```
>
> If None (default), s = len(w) which should be a good value if 1/w[i] is an estimate of the standard deviation of y[i]. If 0, spline
>   will interpolate through all data points.

In my experience, when you are using spline, you are going for the looks and not trying to fit a function you actually want to use later, so you'll probably have to check by hand if it actually does look good. I'd probably just take a look at the data and then make 3-4 versions with a for loop and check which one I find prettier :)